# Synchronize one file from one web server to another

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line-interface

I want to write one php script that will copy one particular file from one web server( linux ) to another( linux ).

Answer (score 0):

You could execute rsync in PHP like so.

```
exec('rsync -ruva --progress /local/file.png user@remote.server.com:/tmp/file.png');
```

Check [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) for information on how to setup passwordless ssh for rsync to run.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use *fopen* and *fgets* (see also http://php.net/manual/de/features.remote-files.php)